# Cannot rename date time column with Laravel Migrtions

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, migration

I want to simply rename my one column although it keeps saying

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1067 Invalid default value for 'sendReminderCouple48' (SQL: ALTER TABLE sendIntakes CHANGE sendReminderCouple36 sendReminderCouple48 DATETIME DE  
  FAULT 'NULL')
```

Currently its `sendReminderCouple36` - `DATETIME` - `NULLABLE`

All I want to do is rename it to `sendReminderCouple48`

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('sendIntakes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->renameColumn('sendReminderCouple36', 'sendReminderCouple48');
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::table('sendIntakes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->renameColumn('sendReminderCouple48', 'sendReminderCouple36');
    });
}
```

Note: I do not want to do any strict changes in my config file.

Comment: According to https://github.com/flarum/core/issues/1211, Version 2.7.0 (and 2.7.1) of Dbal has been released. I believe this should fix the issue, haven't tested it out. Just throwing it out for anyone still tracking this issue and waiting for the dependency to get fixed.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably related to [issue #22050](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/22050) on the Laravel framework. Are you running MariaDB as your database engine?

Following the advice in the thread, you might try changing the default value on the column before doing the rename call:

```
Schema::table('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('name')->default(null)->change();
});
Schema::table('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->renameColumn('name', 'description');
});
Schema::table('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('description')->default(null)->change();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing the type to a text - rename - then back to date time

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('sendIntakes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->text('sendReminderCouple36')->default(null)->nullable()->change();
    });

    Schema::table('sendIntakes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->renameColumn('sendReminderCouple36', 'sendReminderCouple48');
    });

    Schema::table('sendIntakes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->datetime('sendReminderCouple48')->default(null)->nullable()->change();
    });
}

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('sendIntakes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->text('sendReminderCouple48')->default(null)->nullable()->change();
        });

        Schema::table('sendIntakes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->renameColumn('sendReminderCouple48', 'sendReminderCouple36');
        });

        Schema::table('sendIntakes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->datetime('sendReminderCouple36')->default(null)->nullable()->change();
        });
    }
```